# Can't install Homebrew on Catalina

Tags: homebrew, macos-catalina

I have both Xcode and command line tool installed. I am trying to install Homebrew on Catalina.
Its not installing this is what I get

```
   ==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
   mkdir: /usr/local/bin: Not a directory
   Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

On terminal, just run:

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks,  It did install but when I run 'brew help' it says 'brew: command not found'

Comment: @Kumarm If homebrew installed, maybe you can find it in `/usr/local/bin/brew`, If not, may be there are some error while install with install.sh

Comment: its not installed